# Is it possible to give commands to gdb without stopping the debuggee?

Tags: debugging, gdb

Gameconqueror can update the variables it found continuously without stopping the program it's tracing. But as I know you have to use ptrace() to gain access of the specified program and when you do that it automatically stops the debuggee. But somehow Gameconqueror manages to do it's job without interrupting the debuggee(and it updates itself like every half second).

I think if Gameconqueror can do it, also gdb should be able to do it. I tried to enter some commands after continuing the debuggee, gdb doesn't give any error but also doesn't display anything. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make use of asynchronous mode within `gdb`.  This is documented here:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Background-Execution.html#Background-Execution

For example:

```
(gdb) continue &
```

Will continue your program and then immediately return to the command prompt, allowing you to issue further commands while your program is still running.

If you want to stop your program you need to use the `interrupt` command, as the usual `Ctrl`+`c` will not work.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it asap

Comment: But what if the debuggee only have 1 thread? The method you mentioned works but it's not available every time. What should I do when async mode isn't supported?

Comment: Nvm, I got it. You should also add & before attaching. Thank you again. You don't know how this was important for me. Thank you! May the lottery hit you twice in a row on the same day!